# Odd C error: Adding a print statement before a line makes it run, but it errors without it

Tags: c

I'm writing a basic tokenizer to practice my C, but am running into an odd error. What am I doing wrong?

This crashes:

```
char* makeToken(char* string, char deliminator)
{
   char* token;
   char* counter=token;
   char currentChar;
   string-=1;
   while((currentChar=*(string+=1))!=deliminator)
   {
    *counter=currentChar;
    counter++;
   }

   *counter='\0';

   return token;
}
```

But this runs fine:

```
char* makeToken(char* string, char deliminator)
{
   char* token;
   char* counter=token;
   char currentChar;
   string-=1;
   while((currentChar=*(string+=1))!=deliminator)
   {
    printf("Making token\n");
    *counter=currentChar;
    counter++;
   }

   *counter='\0';

   return token;
}
```

Comment: 0) `char* token;   char* counter=token;` : `token` is not initialize. 1)`string-=1;` is probably UB.

Comment: Why not try the principle that one line of code  just does one thing

Comment: BLUEPIXY, what do you mean by UB?

Comment: Ub = undefined behaviour

Comment: token and counter point to nowhere in particular, suggest making use of malloc() and/or realloc()

Comment: suggest using: for(int i = 0; string[i] && string[i] != deliminator; i++ ) { token[i] = string[i]; }

Comment: @Evando `char aStr[] = "Abracadabra bla bla bla"; char *token=makeToken(aStr, ' ');`..`string-=1;` <- made invalid pointer. `*(string+=1)` <- use invalid pointer. this behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a moron and wasn't initializing the pointer. After doing that correctly it worked fine. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions give error on my machine. Probably because of no garbage collection in C, the second version seems to work on your machine.

There are several problems with the code but here's a working version

```
char* makeToken(char* string, char delimiter)
{
   //You need to initialize token
   char* token=malloc(strlen(string)); // The token can be as long as the string
   char* counter=token;
   char currentChar=*string;
   if(token==NULL){
      return NULL;
   }

   //if delimiter does not exist the loop must end
   while(currentChar!=delimiter&&currentChar!='\0')
   {
    *counter=currentChar;
    counter++;
    string++;
    currentChar=*string;
   }
   *counter='\0';
   return token;
}
```

Comment: 1) in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() and family of functions.   2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() and family of functions to assure the operation was successful

Comment: You are forgetting the null character in malloc

Comment: Why the counter variable?

Comment: personally i wouldn't use it. But here it is used to copy values from string, token is used to store the pointer to first character

Answer (score -1):

I think it has nothing to do with `printf`.

You may try `char* counter=token;` instead of `char* counter;`

`counter = token` is needless when initializing.